# MS ACcess Make textboxes visible upon button click

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

At every button click I want to be able to make "visible" 4 textboxes and 4 labels. I am not sure how to do this using VBA code.

Here is what I have tried out so far:
There are no errors produced but I do not know how to proceede from here.

```
Private Sub Command36_Click()

Static Counter As Integer
Dim Name As String
Dim Name2 As String
Dim Count As Integer

Counter = Counter + 1

Name = "Label" & Counter
Name2 = "Text" & Counter
Command36.Caption = Name & Name2

For Count = 1 To Count = Counter
```

Microsoft Access Forms, VBS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
Private Sub Command36_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim Name2 As String
Dim Count As Integer


   For Count = 1 To 4
      Name = "Label" & Counter
      Name2 = "Text" & Counter
      Command36.Caption = Name & Name2
   Next

End Sub
```

I do not quite see what is the point of the above.

This might be of more use, if, as you say, you want to make something visible:

```
   For Count = 1 To 4
      Name1 = "Label" & Counter
      Name2 = "Text" & Counter
      Me(Name1).Visible = True
      Me(Name2).Visible = True
   Next
```

Do yourself a favour and make sure you give controls "real" names, not Command36, but something like `cmdShowLabel`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was planning to change the names to "real names" once the test run was complete.

Comment: Good idea. And watch out for reserved words, too. `Name`, in particular, is a dangerous name for anything, so I hope it is just an example.